# Catching exceptions thrown by the FileSystemWatcher listener thread

Tags: c#, exception, filesystemwatcher

I am trying to figure out a way to catch exceptions thrown by `FileSystemWatcher` these seem to happen randomly as I have noticed from the crash reports logs for my software. The crash is not frequent as it only happened twice last month but its annoying and I would love to fix it. The exception in question seems to be related to files having invalid characters in their paths. I am not sure if that is the case or if the event raised is malformed. So far all I know is the stack trace of the exception:

```
Top-level Exception
Type:        System.ArgumentException
Message:     Illegal characters in path.
Source:      mscorlib

    Stack Trace: 
    at System.IO.Path.GetFileName(String path)

    at System.IO.FileSystemWatcher.MatchPattern(String relativePath)

    at System.IO.FileSystemWatcher.NotifyFileSystemEventArgs(Int32 action, String name)

    at System.IO.FileSystemWatcher.CompletionStatusChanged(UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes,   NativeOverlapped* overlappedPointer)

    at System.Threading._IOCompletionCallback.PerformIOCompletionCallback(UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* pOVERLAP)
```

From the stack trace it is clear that the exception is raised within the execution context of the listener before raising the callback events to my application. I was wondering if there is anyway to catch such an exception and continue execution, ignoring the event.

I tried encapsulating my watcher callbacks' body with `try/catch` blocks but it seems that the execution never reaches the callbacks and its really frustrating as I am now starting to think that it is a bug in the .Net framework

Comment: Is it raised in the unhandledexception event?

Comment: The full path cannot contains the following characters: " < > |

Comment: @SimonWhitehead Yes that's how I caught it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried registering the OnError event?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.onerror%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

EDIT:

The only thing left is ThreadException and UnhandledException:

```
    // Add handler to handle the exception raised by main threads
    Application.ThreadException += 
    new System.Threading.ThreadExceptionEventHandler(Application_ThreadException);

    // Add handler to handle the exception raised by additional threads
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += 
    new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(CurrentDomain_UnhandledException);
```

Comment: I'm not sure that you will receive a ThreadException but you have a chance to receive an UnhandledException. In the handler you may have to stop and restart your file watcher (the exception will probably break it)

Comment: Thats how I caught the exception in the first place. The application is massive with lots of components, it's not practical to filter exceptions here.

Comment: Do you have any chance the get the path the FileSystemWatcher is attached? Because I checked the .net source code and the only way that this exception with this stacktrace can occur is, when you have any invalid characters in your path (as mentioned by Renaud - additionally any char < 32).