# How to catch exceptions thrown by System.IO.FileSystemWatcher

Tags: c#, filesystemwatcher

I have a `System.IO.FileSystemWatcher` that monitors files changes in certain folders.

From time to time, (and, I am not entirely sure how), a badly formatted file is create/renamed and it throws an exception.

I do not know, (or control), who created the badly formatted filename, I don't even know how they manage to do it.

But I would like to guard my code against those edge cases.

The stack trace caught by `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException` just before my app exist.

```
Stack Trace:
    at System.IO.Path.CheckInvalidPathChars(String path, Boolean checkAdditional)
    at System.IO.Path.GetFileName(String path)
    at System.IO.FileSystemWatcher.MatchPattern(String relativePath)
    at System.IO.FileSystemWatcher.NotifyFileSystemEventArgs(Int32 action, String name)
    at System.IO.FileSystemWatcher.CompletionStatusChanged(UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* overlappedPointer)
    at System.Threading._IOCompletionCallback.PerformIOCompletionCallback(UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* pOVERLAP)
```

The actual error in `CheckInvalidPathChars`:

```
...
if (PathInternal.HasIllegalCharacters(path, checkAdditional))
    throw new ArgumentException(Environment.GetResourceString("Argument_InvalidPathChars"));
...
```

That error happens just before the delegates are called.

So, how can I catch the error thrown by `FileSystemWatcher`, (thrown by `System.IO.Path`)?

Comment: I see a duplicate here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21450296/catching-exceptions-thrown-by-the-filesystemwatcher-listener-thread but alas there's no accepted answer and the suggestion made there (attach to the `OnError` event) don't seem to help.

Comment: Do you monitor a file share (on a NAS or something similar)? Note that files/directories on file shares provided by systems running some Unix-like OS (Linux, *BSD, etc...) can contain characters that are illegal in Windows, which would make FileSystemWatcher stumble.

Comment: @Rook, `OnError` is not called in that case, the exception is thrown when checking if the pattern matches.

Comment: @elgonzo, no, I do not monitor any shares, I monitor Windows 10 folders. But even if I was monitoring Unix-like files, I would want my app to not exit due to an unhandled exception ...

Comment: Looks like `FileSystemWatcher` has suffered from this sort of problem for many years, and has an even longer history of being a bit flaky. Might be worth looking to see if there are some alternatives that will work for you (such as [this one](https://github.com/dotnet/corefxlab/tree/master/src/System.IO.FileSystem.Watcher.Polling)... NB, I know nothing about it other than it might be useful).