# FileSystemWatcher Illegal Characters only on CD

Tags: c#, .net, filesystemwatcher, illegal-characters

Super odd problem, so I will do my best to explain. Programming C# using FileSystemWatcher and everything works great on USB/hard drives. On a CD/DVD, some files/directories repeatedly crash the program. The unhandledexception states illegal characters in file path; however, it does not appear that there are any. One example that predictably will crash the program is
G:\testing\testing\FileCheck\FileCheck\App.config
but if I slightly modify to
G:\testing\testing\FileCheck2\FileCheck\App.config
the program works fine. No illegal characters were removed and the first path ALWAYS fails while the second path ALWAYS works.

Here is the exception args

```
System.UnhandledExceptionEventArgs G:\testing\testing\FileCheck\FileCheck\App.config
System.ArgumentException: Illegal characters in path.
   at System.IO.Path.CheckInvalidPathChars(String path, Boolean checkAdditional)
   at System.IO.Path.GetFileName(String path)
   at System.IO.FileSystemWatcher.MatchPattern(String relativePath)
   at System.IO.FileSystemWatcher.NotifyFileSystemEventArgs(Int32 action, String name)
   at System.IO.FileSystemWatcher.CompletionStatusChanged(UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* overlappedPointer)
   at System.Threading._IOCompletionCallback.PerformIOCompletionCallback(UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* pOVERLAP)
```

If anyone has experience to prevent the error from occurring that would be amazing; otherwise, what is the best way to catch FileSystemWatcher errors so that they do not crash the program.

Comment: Have you tried checking the path against [Path.GetInvalidPathChars](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.getinvalidpathchars?view=net-5.0) ?

Comment: Please share a screenshot of the command prompt. Make sure the active folder in that command prompt is `G:\testing\testing\FileCheck\FileCheck` and it is visible that that is the current directory.

Comment: Er, wait. What's the point of a FileSystemWatcher on a **CD/DVD**?

Comment: A wild guess since you are working with `\t` the problem could be unescaped \ and `\t` getting interepreted as tab.

Comment: @Fildor - CD/DVD can be writable

Comment: @RandRandom That doesn't explain why the change makes it work.

Comment: `On a CD/DVD, some files/directories repeatedly crash the program.` What program is writing to the CD / DVD to cause the issue?

Comment: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/35f24877-48c7-4740-bb18-772469ecfa3e/filesystemwatcher-crash?forum=winserverpowershell / https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52505926/how-to-catch-exceptions-thrown-by-system-io-filesystemwatcher / https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21450296/catching-exceptions-thrown-by-the-filesystemwatcher-listener-thread

Comment: _"The FileSystemWatcher can watch disks as long as they are not switched or removed. **The FileSystemWatcher does not raise events for CDs and DVDs**, because time stamps and properties cannot change. ..."_ - [FileSystemWatcher - Events and Buffer Sizes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesystemwatcher?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-5.0#events-and-buffer-sizes) (emphasis by me)

Comment: ^^ Which doesn't explain that specific Exception, however.

Comment: @Fildor - though OP is getting an event `CompletionStatusChanged` and says `G` is a CD

Comment: @RandRandom Yep, that's odd.

Comment: Does setting https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesystemwatcher.internalbuffersize?view=net-5.0 to 64KB stop the issue?

Comment: @Fildor FSW has been 'working' to raise events on change however it looks like the threads you posted have similar problems with seemingly no solution. I have tried checking against GetInvalidChars with no success. Looks like I may need to try another approach. Thank you!

Comment: @mjwills it is a windows service monitoring when files are copied to the disk. Looks like is just a known issue based on what you said

Comment: @mjwills the buffer is already at 64 kb, no affect